# Adding an Immutable Array Slows Down a Thread

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

I have encountered a bit of a paradox that I am trying to understand. Basically I have two variants of an object in a threaded setting - the variants only differ in that one has an immutable array of immutable objects of fixed length, and yet this second variant is considerable slower than the first. Here is the set up:

```
final class Object {
public Pair<Long, ImmutableThing> cache,

public ImmutableThing getThing(long timestamp) {
    if (timestamp > cache.getKey()) { 
        ImmutableThing newThing = doExpensiveComputation(timestamp);
        cache = new Pair(newThing.getLong(), newThing);
        return newThing; }
    else { return cache.getValue()}
```

This first version shows much better performance for the getThing method: It looks up the cache, if the data is valid it returns it, otherwise does a fairly expensive computation, updates the cache, and returns the new value. I understand this is not thread safe as written, but here is the second variant:

```
final class SlowerObject {
    public Pair<Long, ImmutableThing> cache;
    public final ArrayList[ImmutableThing] timelineOfThings;

    public ImmutableThing getThing(long timestamp) {
        if (timestamp > cache.getKey()) { 
            ImmutableThing newThing = findInTimelineOfThings(timestamp);
            cache = new Pair(newThing.getLong(), newThing);
            return newThing; }
        else { return cache.getValue()}
```

In this second variant, we pre-compute an array which stores all the possible values of the things we want to return from getThing (there are only 4 possibilities in my case). Instead of doing a computation if the cache is invalid, we just lookup in the array until we find the correct one, and the computation to figure out which is correct is nearly instant - just comparing long values. The array is never rewritten, just read.

This is all occurring in a threaded environment. Why should the second one be slower?

Comment: You should create an [mcve]. As it stands, we don't know what happens inside all those black boxes. We also don't know the kind of threads that access this, how many of them are there, if there is perhaps a bug that re-calculates the timeline. A runnable program is best.

Comment: Simple: `findInTimelineOfThings` is more expensive than `doExpensiveComputation` for the size of your timeline.